How can I dynamically instantiate nodes from a scene using a constructor?
I have a game_board scene with only a root Node2D and no children.
I wish to programmatically create playing slots on this board.
These slots are to be instantiated from a separate scene file.
Since GDScript doesn't have a constructor, I wrote a static constructor initializing the required members (currently just a slot_id: int)
game_board.gd
extends Node2D

const play_slot_scene = preload("res://scenes/PlaySlot/play_slot.tscn")

func _ready():
    if not play_slot_scene.can_instantiate():
        push_error("Couldn't instantiate play slot")

    var firstSlot: PlaySlot = play_slot_scene.instantiate()
    firstSlot.slot_id = 0;
    
    add_child(firstSlot)
    
    for n in range(1,7):
        var nextChild = firstSlot.constructor(n)
        add_child(nextChild)

play_slot.gd
class_name PlaySlot
extends Node2D

const self_scene = preload("res://scenes/PlaySlot/play_slot.tscn")

@export var slot_id: int

static func constructor(id: int = 0)-> PlaySlot:
    var obj = self_scene.instantiate()
    
    obj.slot_id = id
    
    return obj

The code errors out at var firstSlot: PlaySlot = play_slot_scene.instantiate() because firstSlot is a Node2d obj (not an instance of PlaySlot class).
If I remove the static typing, the next line fails because slot_id does not exist on Node2D.
How do I instantiate these nodes with the right class?
TIA

What you describe suggests that the play_slot.gd script is not attached to the root of the res://scenes/PlaySlot/play_slot.tscn scene.

@Theraot It is indeed attached to it.

At the _ready() function in the game board, instanced child scenes have not bound to the attached script.
In essence, the instanced node is Node2D and can't bind slot_id
The right way
A better way do achieve what I was trying is to simply use the static constructor(). This avoids preloading the PackedScene.
game_board.gd

extends Node2D
@onready var play_slot_grid: GridContainer = %PlaySlotGrid

func _ready():
    generate_play_slots()

func generate_play_slots():
    for i in range(0,9):
        var nextChild: PlaySlot = PlaySlot.constructor(i)
        
        nextChild.name = "PlaySlot" + str(i)
        nextChild.add_to_group("PlaySlots")
        play_slot_grid.add_child(nextChild)

play_slot.gd
class_name PlaySlot
extends Control

# Nodes
const self_scene = preload("res://scenes/PlaySlot/play_slot.tscn")

# Members
@export var slot_id: int

static func constructor(id: int = 0)-> PlaySlot:
    var obj = self_scene.instantiate()
    obj.slot_id = id
    return obj

Using a PackedScene
However, if you must do things using a PackedScene, you need to have an instance ready with instantiate()
game_board.gd

extends Node2D
@onready var play_slot = preload("res://scenes/PlaySlot/play_slot.tscn").instantiate()

func _ready():
    # Doesn't complain because play_slot is not Node2D here
    play_slot.slot_id = 123


I am completely baffled by this issue and the only solution I've found around it is to, instead of hard-coding the definition of play_slot_scene  to a call to preload, defining it as an @export variable and assigning the scene via the editor.  This ... somehow ... makes calling instantiate on the scene actually create a node whose root executes the script on it, whereas using preload somehow does not.
I really liked this engine in 3.x but so far my experience has been quite frustrating due to issues like this.

I think this is the same issue I'm stumbling over too. I want to make a strongly typed scene node which can be used both dynamically in code or attached to another scene (if the user just happens to want one instance for the entire life of their scene). It feels like GDScript is conflating "how to instantiate a node" and "the type of the node" in a way that prevents a good solution. Do you have a "solution" for the case of attaching a node as a scene that's less messy than the use of @onready above?

@David - "The right way" approach doesn't use @onready for the PlaySlots. I did use it for creating a container node. If you were to attach it to self it works without any preload/onready usage.
